# Error de Syntaxis cerca de "Else" SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Buenas noches/días/tardes.

Eh estado haciendo un procedimiento almacenado en el que me inserte datos si es que no existen ya dentro de las diferentes tablas. El problema es que tengo la ídea de como hacerlo pero ahorita me ha surgido un problema que es el siguiente.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Verificar_Dirección(
@localidad varchar(20),
@municipio varchar(20),
@estado varchar(20),
@status_localidad int,
@status_municipio int,
@status_estado int 
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @id_L INT
DECLARE @id_M INT
DECLARE @id_E INT
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT L.id_localidad FROM LOCALIDAD L WHERE L.nombre = @localidad)
BEGIN
    EXEC SP_Insertar_Localidad @localidad,@status_localidad
    SET @id_L =  (SELECT L.id_localidad FROM Localidad L, STATUS_TABLAS S WHERE L.id_status= S.id_status AND L.nombre = @localidad)
    SELECT @id_L
END     
        IF NOT  EXISTS (SELECT M.id_municipio FROM MUNICIPIO M WHERE M.nombre = @municipio)
        BEGIN
            EXEC SP_Insertar_Municipio @municipio,@id_L,@status_municipio
            SET @id_M = (SELECT M.id_municipio FROM MUNICIPIO M, LOCALIDAD L , STATUS_TABLAS S WHERE L.id_localidad = @id_L AND M.nombre = @municipio AND S.id_status = @status_municipio  )
            SELECT @id_M
        END

            IF NOT  EXISTS (SELECT E.id_estado FROM ESTADO E WHERE E.nombre = @estado)
            BEGIN
                EXEC SP_Insertar_Estado @estado,@id_M,@status_estado
                SET @id_E = (SELECT E.id_estado FROM ESTADO E, MUNICIPIO M, STATUS_TABLAS S WHERE M.id_municipio = @id_M AND E.nombre = @estado AND S.id_status = @status_estado)
            END


            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SELECT 'Ya existe este estado'
            END

        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'Ya existe  ese municipio'
        END

ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'YA existe esa localidad'
END
END
GO
```

El problema es que me coloca éste mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro ver como se haría la sintaxys de los if's ya que me imaginaba que era como lo puse.

Muchas gracias desde ya por su ayuda y perdonen la molestia.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error en la sintaxis.

La sintaxis del if/else es, básicamente, esta:

```
if condicion
  SentenciaCumple
else
  SentenciaNoCumple
```

Si dentro de una de estas *secciones* quieres ejecutar varias sentencias, entonces utilizas bloques `begin`/`end`, por ejemplo:

```
if condicion
begin
  SentenciaCumple1
  SentenciaCumple2
end
else
begin
  SentenciaNoCumple1
  SentenciaNoCumple2
end
```

Puedes anidar nuevos `if`'s tanto dentro del `if` como dentro del `else`, pero es allí donde has fallado.  No he seguido la lógica de tu código, pero hablando de manera general, siempre debiera lucir algo como:

```
if condicion
begin
  SentenciaCumple1
  SentenciaCumple2
  -- acá hago otra condicional, pero está contenida completa dentro de este bloque
  -- busca el comentario al final para identificarlo
  if OtraCondicion
  begin
    OtraSentenciaCumple1
    OtraSentenciaCumple2
  end
  else
  begin
    OtraSentenciaNoCumple1
    OtraSentenciaNoCumple2
  end
  -- acá termina el if anidado, pueden haber sentencias posteriores
  SentenciaCumple3
end
else
begin
  SentenciaNoCumple1
  SentenciaNoCumple2
end
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, logré resolver el inconveniente.

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí por una búsqueda a identificar que la respuesta fue de ayuda. Utiliza esta técnica también cuando hagas investigaciones y caigas a StackOverflow, pues fácilmente puedes identificar, cuando hay varias respuestas, cuál es la que le ha servido a quien planteó originalmente el problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].